# Why is the raise_error matcher not working as expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec

I am writing a spec for a controller `POST #update` / `with invalid attributes` context:

#### Controller Spec:

```
context 'with invalid attributes' do
  it "does not change @foo's attributes with empty params" do
    expect(patch :update, id: @foo, foo: attributes_for(:foo,
                                                         start_time: nil,
                                                         end_time:   nil)
                                                       ).to raise_error('ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid')
  end
end
```

#### Model Validations:

```
  validates :name, presence: true
  validate :dates_logic_validation
```

#### Foo's Custom Validation for date logic:

```
def dates_logic_validation
  if !start_time.present? || start_time.nil?
    errors.add(:start_time, "Please double check the starting time")
  elsif !end_time.present? || end_time.nil?
    errors.add(:end_time, "Please double check the starting time")
  elsif (start_time.to_datetime rescue ArgumentError) == ArgumentError
    errors.add(:start_time, 'Please double check the Start Time format')
  elsif (end_time.to_datetime rescue ArgumentError) == ArgumentError
    errors.add(:end_time, 'Please double check the End Time format')
  elsif start_time < Time.now
    errors.add(:start_time, 'Start time must be greater or equal to today\'s date')
  elsif start_time > end_time
    errors.add(:end_time, 'End time must be greater than start time')
  end
end
```

For some reason, the spec above still returns the `ActiveRecord` error / `Validation failed: Start time Please double check the starting time`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to change your parenthesis to curly braces when using a `raise_error` matcher.

**Example**:

```
expect { raise "oops" }.to raise_error(RuntimeError)
```

Source: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-1/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

Comment: I'm curious as to why? What's the reasoning behind it? Also, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just changing parentheses to curly braces will help:

```
expect{patch :update, ...}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

In case of parentheses (RSpec checks result of your code) error  immediately occurs while RSpec evaluates the code, but in case of curly braces (RSpec checks a block of code) RSpec can do all needed setup to correctly handle raised exception.